# How to handle HTML entity nbsp in XSLT. Without changing the input file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert an HTML file into XML file using XSLT (Using [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) 9.0 for transformation).

When I configure and run the XSLT transformation with the HTML file then Oxygen outputs

`The entity 'nbsp' was referenced,but not declared`.

My input html file is:

```
<div><span>&nbsp;some text</span></div>
```

**Note:** I want to know how handle that entity only using the XSLT, I *don't* want to make any changes to the input file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You could use XML Entities to create an XML file that defines the `nbsp` entity, and includes the (broken) XML fragment.**

For example, assume that your fragment is saved as a file called: "*invalid.xml*"

```
<div><span>&nbsp;some text</span></div>
```

Create an XML file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
   <!ENTITY invalid-xml-document SYSTEM "./invalid.xml">
]><wrapper>
&invalid-xml-document;</wrapper>
```

When it that file gets parsed, it will have defined the `nbsp` entity, include the content from the "invalid.xml", and resolve the `nbsp` entity properly.  The result is this:

```
<wrapper>
  <div>
    <span> some text</span> 
  </div>
</wrapper>
```

Then, just adjust your XSLT to accomodate the new document element (in this example the element `<wrapper>`).

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, you're going to need to make changes to the input file.

Either by changing your `&nbsp;` to `&#160;` or by declaring a custom doctype that will do the conversion for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

This is because `&nbsp;` isn't one of XMLs predefined entities.