# How to convert invalid characters in strings before importing them in a XML node?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I have some troubles in making VB.net accepting some invalid characters inside a XML file.

Let's say I have some text that I need to convert into xml nodes and append to a XML node. This text may contain one or more invalid characters just like **& nbsp;** or **& agrave;** or **& eacute;** (in order to display it properly in this page I'm keeping separated the & character and the rest)

For example:

"This is plain & nbsp; wrong"

If I try to import this string within a XML node, the XML parser complains and tells me that the string is not valid. I have to change the **& nbsp;** part into **& #160;**

```
Dim objXML1 As New XmlDocument
Dim objXML2 As New XmlDocument

objXML1.LoadXml("<foo>This is plain &#160; wrong</foo>") ' WORKS
objXML2.LoadXml("<foo>This is plain &nbsp; wrong</foo>") ' Doesn't work
```

Since this issue can happen with a lot of different characters and I don't want to write a method with 500+ "replace" statements that analyse each different problematic characters one by one, could you teach me a better way to handle this problem? Is there a way I can ask VB.net to convert automatically this string in something equal but acceptable by XML ?

If you don't know how to make it in VB.net, a solution to make it in C# would be also welcome, I'm actually stuck :-(

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126999/how-to-handle-html-entity-nbsp-in-xslt-not-changing-the-input-file/9128457#9128457

Comment: You are parsing HTML as XML, and it apparently doesn't have the Document Type Definition (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`), which defines all of the HTML entities.