# I wish to generate a generic code for parsing special characters in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, xslt-2.0

I wish to generate a generic code for parsing special characters in xslt.
I wish to replace all special characters found in any node of the xml document with symbols of my choice.

eg special characters= "&#174"; also" &#169"; etc

I have tried something like follows but nothing happens.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,'&amp;ndash;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'&amp;ndash;','-')" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

the function of character output is:

```
<xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;nbsp;" />
```

I wish to do the opposite i.e replace string with character(replace `&amp;nbsp;` with `&#160;` )

Comment: What is your input document, and what is the output that you expected?

Comment: input document is xml,  I expect to replace characters like &amp;ndash; with &#45;

Comment: The reason I'm asking is to find out whether your input looks like `<a>&ndash;</a>` or like `<a>&amp;ndash;</a>` -- it looks like you're trying to match the second but if your input is like the first, then that doesn't work.

Comment: i have inputs of both kinds, is there any other way to replace <a>&ndash;</a>

Comment: That should be "like `<a>&#x2013;</a>` or like `<a>&amp;ndash;</a>`" my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XSLT 2.0 is at your disposal, use character maps for this. You can find the relevant piece of the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-character-map).

Define the usage of a character map as a top-level element of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output use-character-maps="math-ops"/>
```

Then, determine which characters you'd like to replace with a string of your choice during serialization. A character map consists of `output-character` elements where the `@character` attribute means the character you wish to replace and `@string` its replacement.

The following example ensures that mathematical operators are serialized correctly (that is, for simplicity it outputs capital letters).

```
<xsl:character-map name="math-ops">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x03A3;" string="SIGMA HERE"/><!--Unicode Character 'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA' (U+03A3)-->
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x03A0;" string="PI HERE"/><!--Unicode Character 'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI' (U+03A0)-->
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x2713;" string="CHECK MARK"/><!--Unicode Character 'CHECK MARK' (U+2713)-->
</xsl:character-map>
```

Note that this only has an effect on the actual serialization, not on output you generate with `xsl:result-document`.

To also apply character-maps to this output, specify the `use-character-maps` attribute on the relevant `result-document` elements:

```
<xsl:result-document href="helloworld.xml" use-character-maps="math-ops">
  <hello>
    <world/>
  </hello>
</xsl:result-document>
```

Comment: Very nice solution. But this is xslt 2.0 if I'm not mistaken? I really need to look into version 2.0.

Comment: i am  generating an output using xsl:result-document, Yup its xslt 2.0

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, you're right. It's just that you commented faster than I could add this information :-).

Comment: It is not working for &reg; and &ndash; and &mdash; 
its giving me error "Error reported by XML parser: The entity "ndash" was referenced, but not declared."

Comment: This is a separate question somehow and you could try to google this yourself. But since I am writing anyway, this is because you use a named entity. Try `&#x2013;` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126999/how-to-handle-html-entity-nbsp-in-xslt-not-changing-the-input-file for a similar question and e.g. the unicode reference for characters: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: Please do not edit your question if it completely changes the intent. It doesn't make sense to completely change my answer. This is another question, so please close this question here (e.g. with an accept) and ask another one.