# Replace special characters like &ndash; and &mdash; occuring in an xml document with corresponding code like &#150; etc

Tags: java, xml, regex, templates, xslt

I wish to replace special characters like & ndash; and & mdash; occuring in an xml document with corresponding code like & #150; etc

i have an input xml document containing several special characters

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE BOOK SYSTEM "bookfull.dtd">
<BOOK> 
  <P>The war was between1890&ndash;1900
   <AF>something&mdash;something else</AF>
</P>
</BOOK>
```

there are several other characters like & rsquo; for single quotation

my xslt code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


<xsl:param name="pDest"
    select="'file:///d:/LWW_Book_ePub_Transform/Epub_ZipCreation/XSLT_Transform/Output/'" />

<xsl:template-match="P">
<html>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</html>
</xsl:template-match>

<xsl:template-match="AF">
.....
<xsl:apply-templates/>
.....
</xsl:template-match>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my java codes for parsing is as follow (i am making use of saxon9.)

```
package com.xsltprocessor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ParseUsingSAX {

public ParseUsingSAX() {
}

public void parseBookContent(String xsltFile) {
    try {


        //File inputXml = new File("D:\\data\\myxml.0f");
        File xslt = new File(xsltFile);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xslt)));
        Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();
        Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(inputXml));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult();
        xformer.transform(source,result);           
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IO exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

i am getting the output after transformation as

```
<html>
The war was between1890&ndash;1900
</html>
```

expected output

```
<html>
The war was between1890&#150;1900
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `xsl:character-map` element  that controls output serialization.

```
<xsl:character-map name="dashes">
    <xsl:output-character character="&ndash;" string="&#150;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

You also have to declare

```
<xsl:output use-character-maps="dashes"/>
```

as a top-level element to ensure that the character mapping is used.

As I mentioned in my comments, `&ndash;` is an HTML named entity that needs to be declared in XSLT. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870/using-a-html-entity-in-xslt-e-g-nbsp) discussion for more detail.

Embedded into the stylesheet you show (this outputs dummy strings "MDASH" and "NDASH" - just for illustration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY ndash  "&#x2013;" >
<!ENTITY mdash  "&#x2014;" >
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output use-character-maps="dashes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:character-map name="dashes">
    <xsl:output-character character="&ndash;" string="NDASH"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&mdash;" string="MDASH"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:param name="pDest"
    select="'file:///d:/LWW_Book_ePub_Transform/Epub_ZipCreation/XSLT_Transform/Output/'" />

  <xsl:template match="BOOK">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AF|P">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this does not have an effect on output produced with `xsl:result-document` (since you did not show your entire stylesheet). For more info on character-maps please refer to [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328857/i-wish-to-generate-a-generic-code-for-parsing-special-characters-in-xslt/21329030#21329030) and the official [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-character-map).

Comment: i have already tried that  but character map does not work on &dash and mdash  you can replace &#150; with a string

Comment: `&ndash;` is a named HTML entity. Try my edited answer instead.

Comment: also on trying to replace ndash with a string i get the following error            SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The entity "ndash" was referenced, but not declared

Comment: Do you actually want to replace `–` with &#150, or was that an example of the syntax? Using control characters in XML is strongly discouraged.

Comment: i want the output as either - or &#150  as my reader can recognize both of them, my reader does not recognize &ndash;

Comment: Oh. I get it. Some browsers treat `&#150;` as a en-dash because they treat the obviously incorrect character code as if it was the code point in CP-1252. Don't depend on error-fixing behaviour; use the actual correct code; `&#x2013;` or `&#8211;`. Some things will take you at your word with `&#x150` and actually put that control character in there ("start of protected area" for block-oriented terminals).

Comment: Fine can i replace &ndash; with &#x2013;

Comment: Yes, `&#x2013` is a valid way to represent `–`, though it might be simpler just to output `–` if that will work.

Comment: i am unable to do just that

Comment: @JonHanna: You diagnosed it correctly, yet the question is how exactly to to what you describe in XSLT.

Comment: Yeah, now I know precisely what's wanted, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @user3155839: Declare the HTML entities in your code. See my edited answer.

Comment: @user3155839 well I said about the DTD too (though it's the input XML that needs it, since that's where the entity references are). Can you check that the input XML is indeed validated (check that bookfull.dtd is touched by this) and that the DTD does indeed contain the entity directly or indirectly?

Comment: the dtd contains reference to ent file

Comment: Seems like Jon Hanna's answer has solved your problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

Either the DTD mentioned at `<!DOCTYPE BOOK SYSTEM "bookfull.dtd">` will include the entity references used (like `&ndash;`) or it is in error (or I suppose the input XML could have been in error in trying to use an entity it should be able to use).

If it does include them, then you need to set your XSLT processor to validate the document according to its DTD. (I don't know how to do this in your case, as I know the XSLT part of the problem, but not the specifics of how to use XSLT in Java).

If not, you'll have to fix it.

Get a copy of `http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/w3centities-f.ent` (while it would work to just reference that URI itself, the W3 would prefer if you didn't, and you'll not have better performance this way).

Then create your own bookfull.dtd that includes:

```
<!ENTITY % w3centities-f PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES Combined Set//EN//XML"
    "w3centities-f.ent">
%w3centities-f;
```

Or alternatively, that includes the contents of that file directly within the DTD.

Now in interpreting the input document, the entity references can be resolved. For example, `&ndash;` in the above is defined by:

```
<!ENTITY ndash            "&#x02013;" ><!--EN DASH -->
```

Or in other words; "whenever `&ndash;` appears, replace it with `–`".

This happens at the XML parsing step prior to the XSLT stylesheet being run, so as far as the XSLT is concerned, the content it received contained `–`, not `&ndash;`, and it treats it as such.

Comment: Thank you soo much, it seems my ent file is corrupt it works with the one you provided