# clojure xml parsing slow when dtd used

Tags: xml, performance, validation, clojure

I'm using `clojure.data.xml/parse` to parse xml. Unfortunately the xml being sent back from the server is malformed because it includes escaped unicode and special characters and no dtd. I get around this by manually inserting

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"
 \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"`

into the xml, however when I do this the parsing time goes from <1 second to over 15.

So far I've turned off validation by passing `:validating false` to the parse function, however this is suboptimal. Is there a way to speed this up?

**Edit:** An example of a document sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
  <entry>
    <id>192</id>
    <title>A book &mdash Title</title>
    <synopsis>A long-winded, multi-paragraph synopsis with unicode</synopsis>
  </entry>
</book>
```

Error: XMLStreamException ParseError at [row,col]:[30,267]
Message: The entity "mdash" was referenced, but not declared.  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next (XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)

Comment: Can you share an example of the XML document?  That would help in reproducing what you're seeing.

Comment: Sure, there's an example of one problem child.

Comment: The delay in parsing when using the DTD is very likely to the parser actually fetching the DTD, it's best practice to save the DTD locally instead of referencing one at the w3.org's website.  Saving a copy of the DTD locally and reference it with a local path will speed that part up.  For the entity resolution (mdash), the entities need to be part of the DTD, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523574/replace-special-characters-like-ndash-and-mdash-occuring-in-an-xml-document

Comment: @KyleBurton Thanks, a local dtd fixed the issue completely, down to <1 second again.

Comment: The 'proper' way to handle this is implement an ``EntityResolver`` that can map from the external url(s) to some local resource. You can then ``(parse xml :resolver my-local-resolver)`` See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The delay in parsing when using the DTD is very likely to the parser actually fetching the DTD, it's best practice to save the DTD locally instead of referencing one at the w3.org's website. Saving a copy of the DTD locally and reference it with a local path will speed that part up. For the entity resolution (mdash), the entities need to be part of the DTD, see:
>
> [Replace special characters like &ndash; and &mdash; occuring in an xml document with corresponding code like &#150; etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523574/1113772)