# Retaining special characters as output using XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, html-entities

The issue that I'm facing is regarding the retention of special characters even after XSLT transformation. My source XHTML file contains several special characters like `&nbsp;`, `&mdash;`, `&rsquo;`; which upon XSLT transform, are ignored.

I tried various answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523574/replace-special-characters-like-ndash-and-mdash-occuring-in-an-xml-document) and [this](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/oreilly/java/news/javaxslt_0801.html).

If I'm manually changing the values of the special characters into their corresponding Unicode representations, the characters are retained in the output.

For e.g. Changing `&nbsp;` into `&#160;`, it results in a space in the output. Kindly refer below some sample documents :

**Source XHTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:text="http://giraffe.wkle.com/text" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
    <body>
        <div class="section" id="section_1">
            <p id="para_1" class="para">Content&nbsp;of&nbsp;paragraph&mdash;1.</p>
            <p id="para_2" class="para">Content&nbsp;of&nbsp;paragraph&mdash;2.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSL Template :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='p']/text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:text="http://giraffe.wkle.com/text">
    <body>
        <div class="section" id="section_1">
            <p class="para" id="para_1">Content of paragraph—1.</p>
            <p class="para" id="para_2">Content of paragraph—2.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Actual Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:text="http://giraffe.wkle.com/text">
    <body>
        <div class="section" id="section_1">
            <p class="para" id="para_1">Contentofparagraph1.</p>
            <p class="para" id="para_2">Contentofparagraph2.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Limitations :**

1. I don't have the access to modify the source XHTML content or its DTD.
2. The version of XSLT is 1.0.

Kindly let me know if there's any way that I can transform the special characters using their Unicode values and retain them in my output XML document.

**Update :**

I use this piece of Java code to invoke the transformation :

```
public class XSLTUtil {

    public static String processXHTML(String sourceFileName, String outputXhtml, String xslFilePath) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docbuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docbuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(sourceFileName));

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputXhtml);
            fis = new FileInputStream(xslFilePath);
            TransformerFactory transformfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Templates xsl = transformfactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(fis));
            Transformer transformer = xsl.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement()),new StreamResult(fos));
            return outputXhtml;
        } finally {
            if(fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            if(fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String sourceFileName = "C:\\source.xhtml";
        String outputXhtml = "C:\\output.xhtml";
        String xslFilePath = "C:\\xslTemplate.xsl";
        String result = "-1";
        try {
            result = processXHTML(sourceFileName, outputXhtml, xslFilePath);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Result : "+ result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor on which platform do you use, how exactly do you run the transformation?

Comment: I'm using XSLT1.0, Apache Xalan processor. I'm invoking the transformation using Java. Please check the update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with **Apache Commons Lang3 StringEscapUtils**.
Needing the library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Read the content first and replace all entities to real text.

```
public static String processXHTML(String sourceFileName, String outputXhtml,
        String xslFilePath) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        TransformerException {

    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    Path path = Paths.get(sourceFileName);
    String source = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
    source = source.replaceAll("\\&(amp|lt|gt|quot);", "\u0001$1;");
    source = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(source);
    source = source.replace('\u0001', '&');
    byte[] bytes = source.getBytes(charset);
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docbuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    docbuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
            System.out.printf("resolveEntity PUBLIC %s SYSTEM %s%n", publicId, systemId);
            return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
        }
    });
    //Document doc = docbuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(sourceFileName));
    Document doc = docbuilder.parse(bais);
```

I skipped XML entities.

I have short-wired the EntityResolver, as reading and processing the entities (over the net) takes a very long time. It seems you already have something similar installed, as the entities are not replaced.

In resolveEntity return null to see what DTDs are recursively loaded.

Alternatively you could install an **XML catalog**, a local cache of the HTML entity DTDs, of which there are some.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Joop! This answer worked for me. Now I'm able to retain most of the special characters.
Could you pls explain the answer in detail, since I'm new to XSLT and would love to know what we are actually doing, especially in this - `source = source.replaceAll("\\&(amp|lt|gt|quot);", "\u0001$1;");` ?

Comment: XML uses entities for `&, <, >, ", '` (`&amp;, &lt;, &gt;, &quot;, &apos;`) for when they are not part of XML syntax. Those entities you do not want to fill in by unescapeHtml which would happen as they are HTML entities too. So I replace the ampersand `&` with an unused character, U+0001 aka Ctrl-A, before calling unescapeHtml. Afterwards it has to be undone.

Answer (score 0):

*[Obsolete answer to an earlier version of the question]*

Consider using Andrew Welch's Lexev utility. It basically preprocesses the XML to turn the entity references into something that will be retained through XML parsing, and then postprocesses the transformation result to put the entity references back.

http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/

Comment: Thanks for your time, Michael. The utility uses SAXON parser and invokes the same from Java. My specifications are different. (I have updated in my question.) Do you have any methods using only XSLT, that could help solve me this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the DOM code. Creating a DOM when all you want is to transform it to something else is clumsy and inefficient. Saxon and Xalan both run faster if you supply a StreamSource or SAXSource and let them decide their own tree representation. With Saxon, that can be 5-10 times faster and will use a lot less memory.

I don't know why the DOM is losing the entity references. You have given conflicting information about which XSLT processor you are using, so it's not easy to investigate, but because the DOM data model is different from the XSLT/XPath data model (in particular in its handling of entity expansion) getting rid of DOM should solve it.