# Parse XML files with custom entities in Python, Etree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, dtd

My job is to parse XML files and retrieve various reports. I also create and edit XML files using etree in Python. Most of the time, i am stuck in files with custom entities like mdash, nbsp, and so on.

I browsed and found one solution mentioned here [Python ElementTree support for parsing unknown XML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities)

So i added the entity definition [!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;] and worked on it.It works but i need to read them as string, add the entity definition to it, and then carry on my work.

Is this the only way? If i want to parse the XML files with custom entities without adding them to the file, can i do that?

Is there a way to define those entities in the script and parse the XMl files?

Comment: If the files that you work with contain entity references like `&nbsp;` but no corresponding entity declarations, then the files are ill-formed and therefore not really XML files.

Comment: I understand. But can't help it. I have 100k+ XMl files, and still a lot to come. I can't add those entities back to the XML files (which would be my last way). Is there anything i can do without adding them to the files or the way i mentioned, i would like to know.

Comment: This workaround works with lxml but not with ElementTree, unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128457/407651